# How To Get Retransmission Events with TraceProcessing Library?

Tags: c#, .net-traceprocessing

I am after getting the same data which is visible in WPA
[image]
where I can nicely see how lonog specific TCP packets did need to ack, how much data was transferred and if any TCP retransmission or Dup ACKs were present for that connection.

TraceProcessing offers only processor.UseWinINetData() which allows only to get some HTTP traffic which is not what I want to see. Is it possible to get that data or is there some feature missing? The Nuget package has now version 1.5.0 is there some documentation what has changed since 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the library does not expose the TCP/IP data currently, we are working on enabling more data sources in future versions of the library.

As for release notes, v1.0 - v1.5 only contains refactoring work and bug fixes. I will work with the team to get the release notes published in future versions.

Thanks,

Tristan

Comment: I am looking forward to see network data as well. That would make it a perfect library to look at a system holistically.